# Sitecore Database migration to Azure SQL DB

Tags: sitecore, azure-sql-database, sitecore8, sitecore-azure

I have created Sitecore database instances on Azure using the link as below:

https://github.com/olegburov/sitecore-azure-content/blob/master/articles/how-to-deploy-sitecore-databases-to-azure-sql-database.md

But all the tables are blank, data is not imported. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues related to an old version of Management studio... SQL Azure has updated some settings and it require you to update your SQL Management studio to support the new Azure settings. My recommendation would be to update your management studio to 2014 sp1 (you can also get the specific patch, but SP1 already include it) and deploy the data tier application to the SQL Azure instance from management studio...

Answer (score 0):

If you import Sitecore Database (*.bacpac file) into [Azure SQL Database server V12](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-whats-new/), you must use [SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Service Pack-1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058865), which supports V12 starting from [Commutative Update-5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx).

SQL Server 2014 SP1 includes hotfixes that were included in SQL Server 2014 CU1 to CU5.

Otherwise, use Azure SQL Database server V11, which is supported by earlier versions of SQL Server Management Studio. But, it is not recommended since Microsoft has already retired V11 since September 12, 2015 and will shut it down in the future.